# Error when passing multiple values

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, plsql

I have below stored procedure..

it only works when I pass single value like **"BH"** but not when passing multiple values like **"AE", "BH", "US", "FR"**

```
CALL sp_populate_memo_country_companies("BH")
```

returns 5 rows

```
CALL sp_populate_memo_country_companies("BH", "US")
```

throw error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '")' at line 1

here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`127.0.0.1` PROCEDURE `sp_populate_memo_country_companies`(IN param_country varchar(255))
BEGIN
    SELECT locations.location_id, companies.company_name, locations.location_name, first_payroll, last_payroll
    FROM locations
    JOIN country ON country.country_code_alpha2 = locations.country_code
    JOIN companies ON companies.company_id = locations.company_id
    LEFT JOIN payroll ON payroll.location_id = locations.location_id
    WHERE locations.country_code IN (param_country) AND payroll_active = TRUE
    GROUP BY locations.location_id
    ORDER BY companies.company_name;
END
```

Kindly help...

Comment: why use a sproc at all in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This is one (of many) situation where Stored Routines are less useful than one would like.

A possible workaround:  Build a `VIEW` without the `IN` clause, then use the `IN` clause when fetching from the `VIEW`.